# Ethers.js: Call constant method with await does not work

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

If I try to get the result of a constant function call with:

```
let gameCountAwait = await contract.getGameEntry(0);
```

it fails with:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Whereas if using `.then` it works:

```
let gameCount = contract.getGameEntry(0).then(function(res,err){console.log(res[2]);});
```

- Ethers.js Version: 4.0.39
- Provider: Metamask
- Network: Ropsten

Here is the whole code in case that matters:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
// The Contract interface
let abi = [
  "event GameResult(bool won)",
  "function lottery(uint8 guess) returns (bool value)",
  "function getGameCount() view returns (uint value)",
  "function getGameEntry(uint index) public view returns(address addr, uint amountBet, uint8 guess, bool winner, uint ethInJackpot)"
];

// Connect to the network
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);
let contractAddress = "0x7f8b9483b79f735C34820497A1a7f9FB82C9224b";

let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
let gameCount = contract.getGameEntry(0).then(function(res,err){console.log(res[2]);}); //Works!
// let gameCountAwait = await contract.getGameEntry(0); //Does NOT work!
console.log(gameCount);
```

First time ever playing around with Ethers.js. Hope it is a valid alternative to web3.js. Thanks for your support!

Comment: that is js error, you can use await only in async functions. nothing to do with web3 and ethers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

if you don't want to use `async` function, you can try:

```
// ...

let gameCount;
contract.getGameEntry(0).then(function (res, err) {
    gameCount = res[2];
    // ganeCount is only available here
    // to make it available outside, use async/await notation
    console.log(gameCount);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ethers.js is not related to your problem.  This is just generic Javascript requirement, that `await` may only be used inside asynchronous function.  See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I shouldn't have just copied the example code and use my brain instead...